# What does 'exec' do?

Tags: command-line, execute-command

I recently meant to run the command `pkexec`, but accidentally managed to run the command `exec` by itself with no options or arguments. I looked in the `man` pages for the description of `exec`, but I still have no idea what it means:

```
DESCRIPTION
       The  exec() family of functions replaces the current process image with
       a new process image.  The functions described in this manual  page  are
       front-ends  for execve(2).  (See the manual page for execve(2) for fur‐
       ther details about the replacement of the current process image.)
```

And actually the description goes on... But the rest of the description didn't help me very much either... So this is really my question, what does the `exec` command do? And did I do anything by just executing it by itself with no options or arguments, just as `exec`? Does it have any relation to the `pkexec` command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"`exec()` family of functions" ... are, well, *functions*. They are used in source code. They are not commands to be executed by users<sup>1</sup>. They are typically used by programs which need to execute another (for example, the shell itself, `sudo`, `pkexec`, etc.). A program which calls `exec` directly will find itself replaced by the `exec`'d program, so typical usage is usually [`fork`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/fork.3posix) and `exec`.

A contrived example would look like:

```
$ cat foo.c 
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
    const char * path = "/bin/echo";
    char * args[] = {"echo", "Hello", "World!", NULL};
    execv(path, args);
}
$ gcc -o foo foo.c
$ ./foo           
Hello World!
```

You can see real-life instances of `exec` usage using `strace` on various programs, including `strace` itself:

```
$ strace -e execve ./foo
execve("./foo", ["./foo"], [/* 52 vars */]) = 0
execve("/bin/echo", ["echo", "Hello", "World!"], [/* 52 vars */]) = 0
Hello World!
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Note how `strace` itself uses `exec` to call the program, and then the program in turn calls `exec`.

---

<sup>1</sup> ... except for [the `exec` shell builtin](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_20), which is a shell feature.

`exec` the shell builtin is like the `exec` functions in that invoking `exec` with a program name causes the shell to be replaced by it. However, common usage of `exec` is usually for modifying or adding [file descriptors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256599/what-are-file-descriptors-explained-in-simple-terms).

Another contrived example:

```
$ exec 3</dev/urandom
$ read -u 3 -n 10
$ echo "$REPLY" | base64 
oZN5Qsn3nAs+1GFUCg==
```

You might think that we could read in from `/dev/urandom` directly. Yes, we could. However, this is useful when:

- we need to read from/write to multiple file descriptors
- we need to replace one or more of the standard file descriptors (for example, send `stdout` to a file for the whole shell session).

Comment: So executing `exec` by itself in Terminal does absolutely nothing then?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda It should do nothing.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda test it out. Compare the outputs of `strace bash -c :` and `strace bash -c exec`

Comment: This is the output, does it look fine: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/12301522/ ?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda it does. Now compare, yet again, to `strace bash -c 'exec true'`. You'll see a lot more function calls.

Answer (score 2):

While doing `man exec` you have encountered the `exec()` family of functions which are basically wrapper over the `execve(2)` system call.

The `exec` you have executed is a shell built-in :

```
$ type -a exec 
exec is a shell builtin
```

Now from `help exec` :

```
Replace the shell with the given command.

Execute COMMAND, replacing this shell with the specified program.
ARGUMENTS become the arguments to COMMAND.  If COMMAND is not specified,
any redirections take effect in the current shell.
```

Normally a new process is created by a combination of `fork(2)-exec()` 
 system calls. Here `fork()` will create a child process with a new PID by duplicating the parent process and then `exec()` replaces the child process with the desired executable we want to run. For example, when we want to run an executable say `top`, the shell calls `fork(2)`, thus creating a child process which is exactly the same as the shell with a new PID and then this newly created process is replaced by `/usr/bin/top` using `exec()` call.

Now in the shell builtin `exec`, the `fork()` is not called, instead `exec()` is called directly so the shell is replaced by the executable directly and the new process will inherit the PID of the shell.

Note that only `exec` without any argument or redirection will not do anything.

Comment: So running `exec` by itself in Terminal does absolutely nothing then?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda This is mentioned in my last paragraph `the fork() is not called, instead exec() is called directly so the shell is replaced by the executable directly and the new process will inherit the PID of the shell.`

Comment: @ParanoidPanda I think you meant only `exec`, then it won't do anything..

Answer (score 1):

in addition to what muru said, exec is a bash builtin command. The following description is copied from bash man page (you can use 'man bash' to view it):

```
       exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments]]
              If  command  is specified, it replaces the shell.  No new process is created.  The arguments become
              the arguments to command.  If the -l option is supplied, the shell places a dash at  the  beginning
              of  the  zeroth argument passed to command.  This is what login(1) does.  The -c option causes com-
              mand to be executed with an empty environment.  If -a is supplied, the shell  passes  name  as  the
              zeroth  argument  to  the  executed command.  If command cannot be executed for some reason, a non-
              interactive shell exits, unless the shell option execfail is enabled,  in  which  case  it  returns
              failure.   An  interactive shell returns failure if the file cannot be executed.  If command is not
              specified, any redirections take effect in the current shell, and the return status is 0.  If there
              is a redirection error, the return status is 1.
```